# recuperar mi mbr de windows10

Tags: windows10

he visto que ayudan con esto tambien, queria preguntaros si me pueden ayudar, tengo dos discos instalados en mi computadora con diferente sistema operativo, windows 10 y ubuntu 18.04, el problema radica en que no entra al windows, logro ver los archivos desde el ubuntu, pero no entra y si uso un disco de inicio me dice que no pudo repararlo y no funciona para actualizaciones de windows 
alguna idea
desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: vi una pregunta similar pero antigua ya y no me sirvió

Comment: lo mas posible es que daño el sistema de arranque de windows se recomienda hacer una copa de seguridad desde ubuntu y despues reinstalar windows 10.

Comment: ver https://superuser.com/a/950042/814139

Answer (score 1):

Así es como reparo el mbr de windows 7, imagino que debe funcionar igual para windows 10

```
- Quemas una imagen de disco con el instalador de Windows y booteas tu equipo
- F8 al salir el logo de Windows
- Entrar al modo recuperación
- Abrir la línea de comandos
- bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Nota que puse un espacio entre `bootrec.exe`  y `/fixmbr`

Comment: voy a ver.. en algun momento se me quedo pegado y no funcionó